# Overloading a method which accepts `object` as default parameter type

Tags: c#-4.0, overloading

I need to be able to call a method and pass in an object of an unknown type
but then have the correct overload called. I also need a default implementation that accepts
`object` as its parameter type. What I'm seeing is that the default overload is the only one that ever gets used.

Here's the gist of what I'm trying to do:

```
class Formatter
{
  private object Value;

  public Formatter(object val){
    Value = val;
  }

  public override string ToString()
  {
    return Format(Value);
  }

  private string Format(object value)
  {
    return value.ToString();
  }

  private string Format(DateTime value)
  {
    return value.ToString("yyyyMMdd");
  }
}
```

Ok, so far so good.  Now I want to be able to do this:

```
public static class FancyStringBuilder()
{
  public static string BuildTheString()
  {
    var stringFormatter = new Formatter("hello world");
    var dateFormatter = new Formatter(DateTime.Now);
    return String.Format("{0} {1}", stringFormatter, dateFormatter);
  }
}
```

The result of `FancyStringBuilder.BuildTheString()` is `"hello world 2012-12-21 00:00:00.000"`, when I expected `"hello world 20121221"`

The problem is that the overload that accepts a `DateTime` is not being called, instead defaulting to the overload which accepts an `object`.  **How can I call the proper method without resorting to a messy switch statement?**

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `Formatter.ToString()`, the override `Formatter.Format(object)` is **always** called.  This is because the overload resolution happens at compile-time, not run-time.  At compile-time, the only thing known about `Value` is that it's an object.

If you really want to distinguish incoming types, you'll need to do so in `Formatter`'s constructor.  In this case, rather than hanging on to the object, you could just call `ToString()` immediately and only store the formatted result:

```
class Formatter
{
    string formattedValue;

    public Formatter(object value)
    {
        formattedValue = value.ToString();
    }

    public Formatter(DateTime value)
    {
        formattedValue = value.ToString("yyyyMMdd");
    }

    public string ToString()
    {
        return formattedValue;
    }
}
```

Note that this does assume that your object isn't changing between the time you create the `Formatter` object and the time `Formatter.ToString()` is called, or at the very least that it's okay to take a snapshot of the string representation at the time the `Formatter` is created.

This also assumes that you know the incoming types at compile-time.  If you want a truly run-time-only solution, you'll have to use the "is" operator or a `typeof()` comparison.

If your goal is just to provide custom ToString() formatting based on the incoming type, I'd probably do it using a list that maps from types to format strings:

```
static class Formatter
{
    private static List<Tuple<Type, string>> Formats;

    static Formatter()
    {
        Formats = new List<Tuple<Type, string>>();

        // Add formats from most-specific to least-specific type.
        // The format string from the first type found that matches
        // the incoming object (see Format()) will be used.
        AddMapping(typeof(DateTime), "yyyyMMdd");
        // AddMapping(typeof(...), "...");
    }

    private static void AddMapping(Type type, string format)
    {
        Formats.Add(new Tuple<Type, string>(type, format));
    }

    public static string Format(object value)
    {
        foreach (var t in Formats)
        {
            // If we find a type that 'value' can be assigned to
            // (either the same type, a base type, or an interface),
            // consider it a match, and use the format string.
            if (t.Item1.IsAssignableFrom(value.GetType()))
            {
                return string.Format(t.Item2, value);
            }
        }

        // If we didn't find anything, use the default ToString()...
        return value.ToString();
    }
}
```

With that, calling code then looks like:

```
Console.WriteLine(
    "{0} {1}",
    Formatter.Format(DateTime.Now),
    Formatter.Format("banana"));
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is because the class constructor takes an `object` as parameter, and then assign that object to variable `Value` which is also an `object`. There for calling Format(object) since `Value` is of type `object`

Try this

```
public override string ToString()
{
    if(Value is DateTime)
      return Format(Convert.ToDateTime(Value)); //this should call the right method

    return Format(Value); //works for other non-custom-format types e.g. String
}
```

Comment: This example doesn't quite work. There is a potential for two dozen or so overloads.

Comment: I think you should only worry about the ones that has custom formats - from your question, it's only date.

Comment: I ended up going with this type of solution. I tried an implementation using a subclass for each formatter, but it created a lot of havoc on the rest of the code base. This was the simplest solution with the least amount of sprawl.